# How to print selectors of DOM objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, combinations

Given a DOM structure like this:

```
<div>
  <div>
    <span>
      <img/>
      <i>
        <span></span>
        <meter></meter>
      </i>
      <a><span></span></a>
    </span>
  </div>
  <nav>
    <form>
      <input/>
      <button></button>
    </form>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Wondering how you take that and then return a flat array of all the selectors:

```
[
  'div > div > span > img',
  'div > div > span > i > span',
  'div > div > span > i > meter',
  'div > div > span > a > span',
  'div > nav > form > input',
  'div > nav > form > button'
]
```

My attempt hasn't gotten anywhere:

```
function outputSelectors(array, node) {
  var tag = node.tagName
  array.push(tag)
  for (var i = 0, n = node.children.length; i < n; i++) {
    var child = node.children[i]
    outputSelectors(array, child)
  }
}

outputSelectors([], document.body.children[0])
```

Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Do you only want the selector of leaf nodes?

Comment: Yes, only leaf nodes.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706837/get-unique-selector-of-element-in-jquery

Comment: ^ I was just gonna link that. Use that code to get the path for every element returned from `document.querySelectorAll("*")`

Comment: I would like to know how to do the algorithm, not use a built in method.

Comment: That is not a built-in method.

Comment: Do you want unique selectors or just the path is enough?

Comment: Just the path is enough. But I would like to try it top-down without any helper methods like the document.querySelector(*) and those.

Comment: By top-down, do you mean that you want to memoize the path as you go down so that for siblings you don't need to calculate the path again?

Comment: Yes, that is correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible, a non-recursive approach going from top (root, to be precise) to bottom:

```js
function collectLeafNodePathes(root) {
  const paths = [];
  const selectorParts = [];
  let el = root;
  while (el) {
    const tagName = el.tagName.toLowerCase();
    if (el.childElementCount) {
      selectorParts.push(tagName);
      el = el.firstElementChild;
      continue;
    }

    paths.push(selectorParts.concat([tagName]).join(' > '));
    do {
       if (el.nextElementSibling) {
         el = el.nextElementSibling;
         break;
       }
       el = el.parentNode;
       selectorParts.pop();         
       if (el === root) {
         el = null;
       }
    } while (el);
  }
  return paths;
}

const selectors = collectLeafNodePathes(document.getElementById('xxx'));
console.log(selectors);
```

```html
<div id="xxx">
  <div>
    <span>
      <img/>
      <i>
        <span></span>
        <meter></meter>
      </i>
      <a><span></span></a>
    </span>
  </div>
  <nav>
    <form>
      <input/>
      <button></button>
    </form>
  </nav>
</div>
```

That last part (do-while loop) is a bit rough around the edges, though; open to any improvement.

I've used helper properties ([**childElementCount**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/childElementCount), [**firstElementChild**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/firstElementChild), [**nextElementSibling**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling)) to skip checking for text nodes and stuff. If that's not an option (because of compatibility reasons), it's easy to either implement polyfills or just 'rewind' the loop on non-element nodes.

Comment: Instead of jsFiddle, why don't you use a stack snippet?

Comment: Because snippets are cumbersome. I'll update my answer with a snippet, but it's easier to build a prototype with fiddle - for me, at least.

Answer (score 1):

You can map all elements on a page using the `getPath` method from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5708130/1835379).

Best try this in your own console, as the snippet takes some time to run, and the snippet's console doesn't seem to handle the output properly.

```js
jQuery.fn.extend({
    getPath: function () {
        var path, node = this;
        while (node.length) {
            var realNode = node[0], name = realNode.localName;
            if (!name) break;
            name = name.toLowerCase();

            var parent = node.parent();

            var sameTagSiblings = parent.children(name);
            if (sameTagSiblings.length > 1) { 
                allSiblings = parent.children();
                var index = allSiblings.index(realNode) + 1;
                if (index > 1) {
                    name += ':nth-child(' + index + ')';
                }
            }

            path = name + (path ? '>' + path : '');
            node = parent;
        }

        return path;
    }
});

const allElements = $("*");
const allPaths = allElements.map((_, e) => $(e).getPath());

console.log(allPaths);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here is a version without jQuery, if that's preferable:

```js
function getPath (node) {
    var path;
    while (node.parentElement) {
        var name = node.localName;
        if (!name) break;
        name = name.toLowerCase();

        var parent = node.parentElement;

        var sameTagSiblings = [...parent.children].filter(e => e.localName === name);
        if (sameTagSiblings.length > 1) { 
            allSiblings = parent.children;
            var index = [...allSiblings].indexOf(node) + 1;
            if (index > 1) {
                name += ':nth-child(' + index + ')';
            }
        }

        path = name + (path ? '>' + path : '');
        node = parent;
    }

    return path;
};

const allElements = document.querySelectorAll("*");
const allPaths = [...allElements].map(e => getPath(e));

console.log(allPaths);
```

Comment: So this algorithm essentially finds every leaf node then builds a path up to the top. Interesting. That cuts out the part of the algorithm of traversing down the nodes, the `*` in jquery. Was wondering if there is a way to build it top down as you go, maybe that is the wrong approach.

Comment: Why jQuery? From OP: *I would like to know how to do the algorithm, not use a built in method.*

Comment: @Ele: There isn't very much jQuery in there. Just slightly more readable code. The algorithm is right there, in plain JS.

Comment: I know, but I think is very verbose the usage of jQuery plugin.

Comment: @Ele: I added a non-jQuery version :-)

Comment: @Cerbrus Nice! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Slightly modifying [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706837/get-unique-selector-of-element-in-jquery) solution to get path and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22289391/how-to-create-an-array-of-leaf-nodes-of-an-html-dom-using-javascript) one to get leaf nodes.

```js
function getPath(node) 
{
  var path;
  while (node.parentNode ) 
  {
    name = node.nodeName;
    if (!name) break;

    var parent = node.parentNode;
    path = name + (path ? ' > ' + path : '');
    node = parent;
  }
  return path;
}

function getLeafNodes() 
{
    var allNodes = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
    var leafNodes = Array.from( allNodes ).filter(function(elem) {
        return !elem.hasChildNodes();
    });
    return leafNodes;
}

var leadNodes = getLeafNodes() ;
var output = leadNodes.map( s => getPath(s) );
console.log(output);
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <span>
      <img/>
      <i>
        <span></span>
        <meter></meter>
      </i>
      <a><span></span></a>
    </span>
  </div>
  <nav>
    <form>
      <input/>
      <button></button>
    </form>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Now what if you have duplicate siblings? Then you won't have valid selectors any more.

Comment: OP hasn't asked for unique selector in his question.

Comment: Hmm, this would work but I would like to try to do it top-down, similar to this:  https://github.com/hughsk/flat/blob/b6633d0f2c1f06080e6fb51913ec5de749b884dc/index.js#L14-L35, was hoping for an answer along those lines. Can't figure it out.

Comment: @gurvinder372: True, but it's not an uncommon use case in HTML

Comment: @Cerbrus In case a valid selector is required (for later access), then I would rather approach this by generating and assigning unique ids to the leaf nodes and keep the array of such ids.

Answer (score 0):

You can create recursive function and check if current element contains children using `children()` method.

```js
const result = []

const getTag = (el) => el.prop('tagName').toLowerCase()
function print(el, prev = '') {
  prev = prev.length ? prev : getTag(el)
  const children = el.children();
  if(!children.length) result.push(prev)
  else {
    children.each(function() {
     let tag = getTag($(this))
      let str = prev + (prev.length ? ' > ' : '') + tag;
      print($(this), str)
    })
  }
}

print($('#start'))
console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="start">
  <div>
    <span>
      <img/>
      <i>
        <span></span>
        <meter></meter>
      </i>
      <a><span></span></a>
    </span>
  </div>
  <nav>
    <form>
      <input/>
      <button></button>
    </form>
  </nav>
</div>
```

To get array of unique selectors you can use `Set` on final result to remove duplicates.

```js
let result = []

const getTag = (el) => el.prop('tagName').toLowerCase()
function print(el, prev = '') {
  prev = prev.length ? prev : getTag(el)
  const children = el.children();
  if(!children.length) result.push(prev)
  else {
    children.each(function() {
     let tag = getTag($(this))
      let str = prev + (prev.length ? ' > ' : '') + tag;
      print($(this), str)
    })
  }
}

print($('#start'))
result = [...new Set(result)]
console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="start">
  <div>
    <span>
      <img/>
      <i>
        <span></span>
        <meter></meter>
      </i>
      <a><span></span></a>
      <a><span></span></a>
    </span>
  </div>
  <nav>
    <form>
      <input/>
      <button></button>
    </form>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Now what if you have duplicate siblings? Then you won't have valid selectors any more.

Comment: @Cerbrus Could you provide example

Comment: Replace `<a><span></span></a>` with `<a><span></span></a><a><span></span></a>`

Comment: You would get two `"div > div > span > a > span"` https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/2712/

Comment: Which wouldn't be valid.

Comment: @Cerbrus Not sure if that was the point of this question but I updated my answer.

Comment: Nice and short +1. Imo, better safe than sorry :D